# Create fanpage on Facebook C# facebookSDK

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

We can create albums upload photos but can we create fan page using faceboook c# sdk?

I am using [this sdk](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) on codeplex!

Comment: Yeh I also want to know that :)